# Printing out a csv line by line in perl

Tags: bash, perl

I have a list of values

```
2018.04.09, 22:39, SPX , 2200 , 10 
2018.04.09, 22:39, SPX , 2225 , 5 
2018.04.09, 22:39, SPX , 2175 , 5
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2585 , 66
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2595 , 33
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2575 , 33
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2580 , 33
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2600 , 33
2018.04.26, 34:03, SPXW , 2590 , 66
```

And I need to put time into these values - just replace the vlaues.

```
2018.04.09 where ticker = `SPX, strikeprice = 2200, orderqty = 10, (string transacttime) like "*22:39.*"
2018.04.09 where ticker = `SPX, strikeprice = 2225, orderqty = 5, (string transacttime) like "*22:39.*" 
2018.04.09 where ticker = `SPX, strikeprice = 2200, orderqty = 5, (string transacttime) like "*22:39.*"
```

And I don't know how to do it in perl do I did in bash. How do I do it in perl?

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
while read -r date time sym str qty
do
echo "
$date where ticker = \`${sym}, strikeprice = ${str}, orderqty = ${qty}, (string transacttime) like \"*${time}*\"
"
done < /tmp/list
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: I thought I needed to build an array of arrays to get this done in perl ? Is there an easier way ?  I an not good with those date structures - hashes of arrays, arrays of hashes, multi level hashes - is there some kind of math I can practive to get good at those data structures in perl

Comment: This is just as easy in Perl as it is in Bash. What have you tried so far? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: An array of arrays? No. Just open the file, read it in a `while` loop, `split` each line, and `print`.

Comment: Your attempt to restore `IFS` [is severely broken](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#OIFS.3D.22.24IFS.22.3B_....3B_IFS.3D.22.24OIFS.22).

Comment: It looks like you have a [bunch of existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A824282+%5Bperl%5D+is%3Aquestion+open) that essentially does the same thing... right?

Comment: How is IFS broken ?

Comment: I didn't say IFS is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic `Text::CSV` usage:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my $parser = Text::CSV->new;

open my $data, '<', 'data.csv';
while (my $row = $parser->getline($data)) {
    # $row is an array reference. dereference by using "@$row"
    print 'the row is: '.join('||', @$row)."\n";
    # or access elements like $row->[0]
    print 'the first element of the row is '.$row->[0];
}
```

Comment: To strip whitespace around separator `Text::CSV->new({ allow_whitespace => 1 });`

Answer (score 2):

See [split](http://p3rl.org/split).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $in, '<', '/tmp/list' or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    my ($date, $time, $sym, $str, $qty) = split /,/;
    print qq(\n$date where ticker = `$sym, strikeprice = $str, orderqty = $qty, (string transacttime) like "*$time*"\n\n);
}
```

If you don't want to get the empty lines around each line, just remove the `\n`'s from the beginning and end of the qquoted string.

Comment: You may have to split on `/\s*,\s*/` to get rid of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Parse::CSV also has very good interface.

```
# Simple headerless comma-seperated column parser
my $simple = Parse::CSV->new(
    file => 'file.csv',
);

while ( my $array_ref = $simple->fetch ) {
   # Do something...
}
```